# Get support and ranking attributes for RFE using Pipeline in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, pipeline, rfe

The code I have so far is below and it works perfectly. However, I would like to print the following **RFE** attributes for each number of features tested: **"rfe.support_[i]"**, **"rfe.ranking_[i]"** and the **name of the selected features** since "i" refers to the index, the first attribute returns True or False (if the columns were selected or not) and the second one returns their respective rankings.

In other words, I would like to print the columns considered in each RFE and that they do not remain as something abstract.

```
# Explore the number of selected features for RFE
from numpy import mean
from numpy import std
from sklearn.model_selection import RepeatedKFold, cross_val_score, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from category_encoders import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

# Get the dataset
def get_dataset(df, target):
    X, y = df.drop(columns = target), df[[target]].values.flatten()
    return X, y

# Get a list of models to evaluate
def get_models(list_num_cols, list_cat_cols):
    num_transformer = Pipeline(steps = [('num_imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy = 'median'))])
    cat_transformer = Pipeline(steps = [('cat_imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy = 'most_frequent')),
                                        ('one-hot-encoder', OneHotEncoder())])
    preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers = [('num', num_transformer, list_num_cols),
                                                     ('cat', cat_transformer, list_cat_cols)])
    models = dict()    
    for i in range(2, 4):
        rfe_dtr = RFE(estimator = DecisionTreeRegressor(), n_features_to_select = i)
        model_dtr = DecisionTreeRegressor()
        models['DecisionTreeRegressor_' + str(i)] = Pipeline(steps = [('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                                                                     ('s_dtr', rfe_dtr), 
                                                                     ('m_dtr', model_dtr)])
    return models

# Evaluate a give model using cross-validation
def evaluate_model(model, X, y):
    cv = RepeatedKFold(n_splits = 10, n_repeats = 3, random_state = 7)
    scores = cross_val_score(model, X, y, scoring = 'neg_mean_absolute_error', cv = cv, 
                             n_jobs = -1, error_score = 'raise')
    return scores


# Define the dataset
X, y = get_dataset(my_df, 'my_target')   # It begins here
# Get the models to evaluate
models = get_models(X.select_dtypes(include = 'number').columns.tolist(), 
                    X.select_dtypes(include = 'object').columns.tolist())
# Evaluate the models and store results
results, names = list(), list()
for name, model in models.items():
    scores = evaluate_model(model, X, y)
    results.append(scores)
    names.append(name)
    print('%s %.3f (%.3f)' % (name, mean(scores), std(scores)))
```

The following is returning errors:

```
models['DecisionTreeRegressor_2'].named_steps['s_dtr'].support_[0] # Returns: AttributeError: 'RFE' object has no attribute 'support_'
models['DecisionTreeRegressor_2'].named_steps['s_dtr'].ranking_[0] # Returns: AttributeError: 'RFE' object has no attribute 'ranking_'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered the question. I'm posting it in case it can help someone. It consists of using "cross_validate", instead of "cross_val_score", with the option "return_estimator = True" to be able to retrieve the pipelines in the different folds and RFE, and access them by index. Then you can use "named_steps".

```
# Explore the number of selected features for RFE
from numpy import mean
from numpy import std
from sklearn.model_selection import RepeatedKFold, cross_val_score, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from category_encoders import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

# Get the dataset
def get_dataset(df, target):
    X, y = df.drop(columns = target), df[[target]].values.flatten()
    return X, y

# Get a list of models to evaluate
def get_models(list_num_cols, list_cat_cols):
    num_transformer = Pipeline(steps = [('num_imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy = 'median'))])
    cat_transformer = Pipeline(steps = [('cat_imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy = 'most_frequent')),
                                        ('one-hot-encoder', OneHotEncoder())])
    preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers = [('num', num_transformer, list_num_cols),
                                                     ('cat', cat_transformer, list_cat_cols)])
    models = dict()    
    for i in range(2, 4):
        rfe_dtr = RFE(estimator = DecisionTreeRegressor(), n_features_to_select = i)
        model_dtr = DecisionTreeRegressor()
        models['DecisionTreeRegressor_' + str(i)] = Pipeline(steps = [('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                                                                     ('s_dtr', rfe_dtr), 
                                                                     ('m_dtr', model_dtr)])
    return models

# Evaluate a give model using cross-validation
def evaluate_model(model, X, y):
    cv = RepeatedKFold(n_splits = 10, n_repeats = 3, random_state = 7)
    output = cross_validate(model, X, y, scoring = 'neg_mean_absolute_error', cv = cv, 
                             n_jobs = -1, error_score = 'raise', return_estimator = True)
    return output


# Define the dataset
X, y = get_dataset(my_df, 'my_target')   # It begins here
# Get the models to evaluate
models = get_models(X.select_dtypes(include = 'number').columns.tolist(), 
                    X.select_dtypes(include = 'object').columns.tolist())
# Evaluate the models and store results
results, names = list(), list()
for name, model in models.items():
    output = evaluate_model(model, X, y)
    results.append(output['test_score'])
    names.append(name)
    print('%s %.3f (%.3f)' % (name, mean(output['test_score']), std(output['test_score'])))
    print(output)  
    print(output['estimator'][0].named_steps['s_dtr'].support_)
    print(output['estimator'][0].named_steps['s_dtr'].ranking_)
    print(output['estimator'][0].named_steps['s_dtr'].support_[2])
    print(output['estimator'][0].named_steps['s_dtr'].ranking_[2])
```

Answer (score 1):

Point is that you haven't *explicitly* fitted the `'DecisionTreeRegressor_2'` pipeline.

Indeed, though [`cross_val_score`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7e1e6d09bcc2eaeba98f7e737aac2ac782f0e5f1/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py#L375) already takes care of fitting the estimator as you might see [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7e1e6d09bcc2eaeba98f7e737aac2ac782f0e5f1/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py#L268), `cross_val_score` does not return the estimator instance, as `.fit()` method does. Therefore you're not able to access the `RFE` instance attributes.

Here's a toy example from your setting:

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression

X, y = make_regression()
models = dict()    
for i in range(2, 4):
    rfe_dtr = RFE(estimator = DecisionTreeRegressor(), n_features_to_select = i)
    model_dtr = DecisionTreeRegressor()
    models['DecisionTreeRegressor_' + str(i)] = Pipeline(
    [
        ('s_dtr', rfe_dtr), 
        ('m_dtr', model_dtr)
    ])

models['DecisionTreeRegressor_2'].named_steps['s_dtr'].support_   # this does not work
```

You might see, instead, that after fitting your model, you'll be able to access the `support_` and `ranking_` attributes:

```
models['DecisionTreeRegressor_2'].fit(X,y)
models['DecisionTreeRegressor_2'].named_steps['s_dtr'].support_   # this works
models['DecisionTreeRegressor_2'].named_steps['s_dtr'].ranking_   # this works
```

Comment: Thanks, I know that works. However, I perform transformations to X within the Pipeline, consider various number of features for RFE and apply cross validation, I would like to print the columns considered in each RFE and that they do not remain as something abstract. Thank you very much again.